# How to update column of the target table from two tables of the columns in oracle?

Tags: oracle

```
tab1:                             tab2:

Prod1_tab:                         prod2_tab:
prod_id       prod_name             prod_id             prod_name
1               aaa                    2                   ddd
2               bbb                    3                   eee
3               ccc                    4                   fff
```

But i want target table like:

```
tab3:

prod_id          prod_name
1                 aaa
2                 bbb,ddd
3                 ccc,eee
4                 fff
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a FULL OUTER JOIN on prod_id.